# gtkwave tcl script for adding specific signals

Tags: tcl, gtkwave

I have a huge `VCD` file that I use in combination with `gtkwave` to observe certain signal behaviors. I have a list of signals stored into a `.txt` file which are the ones that I wish to probe. The thing is that by doing the insertion of the signals manually by hand is a painstakingly long process. So my question here is,

Is there a way, given the `.txt` file to compose a `.tcl` script that filters and adds the designated signals from the list to the waveform editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after scouting on manuals and some `gists` I found here and there seems that there is a load of `gtkwave` instructions one can use that are listed (most of them) on the `gtkwave` manual (Appendix E) [here](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/gtkwave.pdf). So in a nutshell all one has to do is to write a `.tcl` script in the following format:

```
# add_waves.tcl 
set sig_list [list sig_name_a, register_name\[32:0\], ... ] # note the escaping of the [,] brackets
gtkwave::addSignalsFromList $sig_list
```

and then invoke the gktwave as:

`gtkwave VCD_file.vcd --script=add_waves.tcl`

Furthermore, access to the GUI menu options are viable as well via the following syntax in `tcl`:

```
gtkwave::/Edit/<Option> <value>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same situation and implemented the solution provided in the accepted answer.

However, I lost some time parsing from the .txt file, I just hadn't noticed that in that case the escaping of the `[,]` characters is not necessary, it's handled by tcl.

My final script that reads from a `wave_names.txt` file is:

```
proc listFromFile {filename} {
    set f [open $filename r]
    set data [split [string trim [read $f]]]
    close $f
    return $data
}

set sig_list [listFromFile wave_names.txt]

gtkwave::addSignalsFromList $sig_list
```